# Frequent socket/connection time out in SOAP/HTTP protocol

Tags: http, soap, timeout

i am working in a web application project which has .NET based Web 2.0-based features in GUI(means lot of AJAX calls) and axis1 based web services at business layer to serve data...
i see a performance issue in webservice protocol: SOAP/HTTP...since there is going to be lot of AJAX calls i.e. HTTP requests to web server..we may see frequent socket/connection time out issues in production...I want to know does any one have any prior experience in this kind of issue? Any idea how to rectify this?

I googled and found persistent HTTP Connections would improve it...but would like to know your views.
Here is my enviroment details:-
front end: .NET
backend:
tomcat 6.0
axis1
oracle10g 
windows XP

Answer (score 0):

Yes, persistent HTTP connections help to avoid creating new connections, and this is the first thing that comes to mind. Another way is to set socket timeout values on client/server sockets, increase `backlog` value on the server socket(s) (I'm not sure how to do it in Axis*).

Comment: Thanks, but do you see it as a design issue? Do you think above mesaures should make our system 100% socket connection time out free in production?

Comment: Nothing can guarantee it to be 100% free. You should improve it as more as you can, and provide a way to configure the system (timeout, databack) depending on the environment.